# How to ensure the comparison result still hold in multi-threading?

Tags: multithreading, atomic

Suppose there are 3 threads,

Thread 1 and 2 will increase or decrease a global variable X atomically.

thread 1:

```
atomic_increase(X)
```

thread 2:

```
atomic_decrease(X)
```

Thread 3 will check if the X is greater than some predefined value and do things accordingly.

thread 3:

```
if( X > 5 ) {... logic 1 ...}
else {... logic 2 ....}
```

I think the `atomic_xxx` operations are not enough. They can only synchronize the modifications between thread 1 and 2.

What if `X` is changed by thread 1 or 2 **after thread 3 finishes the comparison and enters** `logic 1`.

Do I have to use a mutex to synchronize all the 3 threads when **modifying or reading** the `X`?

### ADD 1

BTW, logic 1 and logic 2 don't modify the X.

Answer (score 2):

In short yes, reads also need to be synchronized in some way, otherwise the risk of inconsistent reads is real. A read performed between the read and write of `atomic_increase` will be inconsistent.

However if `logic 1` or `logic 2` do stuff to `X`, your problems doesn't seem to stop right there. I think then you need the concept of a transaction, where it starts with a read (the `X > 5` thing) and then ends with a write (`logic 1` or `logic 2`).

Comment: Thanks. BTW, logic 1 and logic 2 don't modify the X.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, And the Answer is `happens before` link, Lets say `Thread-1` started executing `atomic_increase` method. It will hold the `lock` and enter the `synchronized` block to update `X`.

```
private void atomic_increase() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        X = X + 1;  // <-- Thread-1 entered synchronized block, yet to update variable X
    }
}
```

Now, for `Thread-3` to run the logic, it needs to read the variable `X`, and if it is `not synchronized` (on the same monitor), the variable `X` read can be an old value since it may not yet updated by `Thread-1`.

```
private void runLogic() {
    if (X > 5) { // <-- Reading X here, can be inconsistent no 
                   happens-before between atomic_increase and runLogic
    } else {

    }
}
```

We could have prevented this by maintaining a `happens-before` link between `atomic` operation and `run_logic` method. If the `runLogic` is `synchronized` (on the same monitor) , then it would have to wait until the variable `X` to be updated by the `Thread-1`. So we are guaranteed to get the last updated value of `X`

```
private void runLogic() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (X > 5) { // <-- Reading X here, will be consistent, since there 
                       is happens-before between atomic_increase and runLogic 
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what your application does. If neither logic 1 nor logic 2 modifies `X`, it is quite possible that there is no need for additional synchronization (besides using an atomic_load to read `X`).

I assume you use intrinsics for atomic operations, and not simply an increment in a mutex (or in a synchronized block in Java). E.g. in Java there is an `AtomicInteger` class with methods such as 'incrementAndGet' and 'get'. If you use them, there is *probably* no need for additional synchronization, but it depends what you actually want to achieve with logic 1 or logic 2.

If you want to e.g. display a message when `X > 5`, then you can do it. By the time the message is displayed the value of `X` may have already changed, but it remains the fact, that the message was triggered by `X` being greater than 5 for at least some time.

In other words, without additional synchronization, you have only the guarantee that logic 1 will be called if `X` becomes greater than 5, but there is no guarantee that it will remain so during execution of logic 1. It may be ok for you, or not.

Comment: So it depends on what logic 1 is.

Comment: @smwikipedia It also depends on what logic 2 is. Without additional synchronization logic 2 will be called when `X <= 5`, but during execution of logic 2 `X` may increase in parallel to, e.g., 6 or more. If it's ok for logic 2, then no problem.